# Is it possible to 'lock' a list item after a deadline?

Tags: list, custom-list

We're trying to set up a list where items have a time limit for their completion, after which they cease to be editable by the user with normal permissions.  Is this possible and if so how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this with workflow.  I would likely set it up to a wait/delay until the completion date or look for a completed status and then change the permissions of the list item.  Here is a step-by-step walk through for changing the permissions.

http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html